# How to bind image with BitmapImage in windows phone 8?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, bitmapimage

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="12,0,9,0">   
    <Image.Source>    
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImgURL}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>   
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I don't know how to bind image with control `BitmapImage`.

Help me!

Comment: Put your model binding class.

Comment: In the code .cs how to binding? Can you tell more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .cs file you set source as below

1.) Give name to your XAML image control like `x:Name="img"`

2.) 
`img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))`

URL = which link you are getting in `ImgURL`

I hope this will helpful to you.

**Edit**

```
ImageSource imgSource = null;
BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
imgSource = bm;
img.Source = imgSource;
```

Comment: I want bindding with Bitmap because Bitmap can clear image cache .

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you could try direct binding from `viewmodel`

```
private Uri _imgURL;

public Uri ImgURL
{
    get { return _imgURL; }
    set
    {
        _imgURL= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImgURL);
    }
}

//Load your data from here
public void LoadData()
{
   Uri = new Uri(@"/sampleImages/cherries_larger.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```